# is any thing wrong with poedit or my settings?

Tags: wordpress

During my theme translation process I am stuck in the middle badly, currently i am following strange issue. Here are my settings:
[image]

and here is in my code file I mean in my theme code:

```
<?php _e('kai'); echo __('ka'); echo _('kami saab');?>
<?php echo _('huh');?>
```

Sorry for that strange words, but its not the case by now. The problem is that its showing only two translate able strings like:

```
echo _('kami saab');
echo _('huh');
```

My problem is why other these are missing? And why not my this works at all?

```
<?php _e('kai', 'kami'); echo __('ka', 'kami');?>
```

Now why not this picking my lines in my translate able strings list? What's wrong with my code or settings ... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, If you check your settings as shown in above screen shot, you are doing one minor mistake, which is that just remove function symbol from end of your provided keywords: For more details check below given Keywords:

```
_e
__
```

and all other code will remain same as it is, and your those strings will be showing translate able as well.

Comment: yeah it works life saver ... I am sorry it was so simple ?

Comment: its good that your problem has been solved. I done a lot of work once I was first trying those out ... and that helped you too ...